# How to create View in SQL Server by using WHERE clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm supposed to create a view named VIEW2 on a training database that includes the following fields:

```
project number, 
project name, 
employee number, 
employee last name, 
job description.
```

Of course this is multiple tables in the FROM statement and I'm supposed to use WHERE clauses to join the tables together.

I'm able to create this easily using SSMS and the JOIN statements but now have been limited to criteria that requires using WHERE clauses to create the JOINS and is confusing the heck out of me. Is it even possible?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. What do you mean when you say "using WHERE to create JOINS"?

Comment: Your question mentions SQL Server's SSMS, but it's tagged MySQL, which is a different DBMS altogther.  Which one is it?

Comment: Yes, you can do joins and add where filters to a view, although this will be 'baked in' and any usage of the view will be filtered by these criteria. Sanity check - by SSMS do you mean SqlServer, not MySql?

Comment: We need the entire table layout at least to give you a hint on the joins.

Comment: my understanding is the view will display above mentioned columns from the tables listed (SQL not MySql...sorry) and use WHERE to create the joins. The tables (EMPLOYEE, ASSIGNMENT, PROJECT and JOB). Is there a reason behind not using INNER JOINS for this particular view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can use a `where` clause to join tables:

```
select  *
from    Projects p
,       ProjectEmployes pe
,       Employees e
where   p.id = pe.project_id
        and e.id = pe.employee_id
```

It is better to use the `on` clause instead:

```
select  *
from    Projects p
join    ProjectEmployes pe
on      p.id = pe.project_id
join    Employees e
on      e.id = pe.employee_id
```

The `on` syntax keeps tables and their relations near eachother.  That is even more pronounced when you join more than three tables!

The `on` clause also seperates relation conditions and filter conditions.  If you use a `join`, the `on` clauses have the relations, and the `where` clause has the filter.

Comment: Those were my thoughts originally. still do not understand why the joins are wanted using the 'where' clause and not the 'JOIN...ON' Seems very ambiguous and unnecessary.